# How to get baseUrl in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

This is a reliable way to get the host url in both SSR and CSR:

```
let host = context.req ? context.req.headers.host : window.location.origin
```

But where to put this so all compoments can access the host? It should be loaded once per page and work with both SSR and CSR.

Comment: Are you using vuex with your application?

Comment: @lix No. I could, if it's the only way

Comment: It might not be the only way, but it's structurally a good choice if your application is going to have many components that will need this information. Other ways might involve making it a static reference within the Vue instance similar to how you might resolve a plugin, but that's generally bad practice.

Comment: Or event emission from components to a main parent component, but that's a great way to just end up with far more code than you need.

Comment: use asyncData in each component to get host url in both ssr and csr

Comment: asyncData only works on page components. You don't want to hand down too much through other components

Answer (score 1):

The `useRequestURL()` composable was introduced in Nuxt version 3.5.0:

```js
const hostname = useRequestURL().hostname   // "example.com"
```

or the host with the port:

```js
const host = useRequestURL().host           // "example.com:3000"
```

More information for `useRequestURL()` can be found in the [Nuxt documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-request-url).

Answer (score 0):

I advice to use `computed`, i think it works any nuxt verion.

```js
computed: {
    url() {
      if (process.client) {
        return window.origin;
      }
      return "";
    },
  },
  
  
  created() {
    console.log(this.url)
  },
```